# How to delete files/folders from source control permanently?

Tags: svn, version-control, coda

I am attempting to delete a folder, and its files and subfolders, from my site's source control under Coda 2 for Mac, and am getting all kinds of errors. I appreciate any direction as to how to properly manage this, since Google searches only seemed to make a simple issue appear more complicated.

- Created/Published new directory in site > "**/l**"
- Created/Published new file in site/l/ > "**index.cfm**"
- Created/Published new subdirectory in site/l/ > "**_includes**"
- Created/Published new file in site/l/_includes > "**header.cfm**"
- Added then Committed **/l/** and **/l/_includes** folders to source control
- Lastly, Added and Committed .cfm files to source control

I have edited and re-published these .cfm files since then, with no problem, but Committing them to source control with the changes has been a problem. I get these errors when trying to commit or update in Coda 2:

**svn commit failed containing working copy admin area is missing**

**svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKCOL request for '[svn folder path here]'**

How can I *completely* remove the /l folder and ALL the files within it under source control, so I can start over fresh? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout a new working copy. Likely, the problem is in your working copy, and the new working copy will work without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Appears your working copy is borked, start by doing a cleanup and seeing if you can proceed from there. If no go after the cleanup, see if you can validate the admin area (no idea how to do this from coda) If it's still not working try a fresh checkout from the repo.